# My Angular web App with PWA does not work when i go offline

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am build a music web app using Angular with PWA, though it is my first time of using PWA in Angular project. but the problem i am facing is that my app does not work when i click offline mode in chrome. the browser always show NO INTERNET CONNECTION when i go offline. please what can i do about this?
below i have my manifest.json content and ngsw-config.json.

###manifest.json###

```
{
  "name": "naipod",
  "short_name": "naipod",
  "theme_color": "#F96816",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

###ngsw-config.json###

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "naipodapi",
    "urls": [
      "https://naipod.com/naipodapi/getsongs"
      
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy" : "performance",
      "maxAge" : "1d",
      "maxSize" : 100
    }
  }
  ]
  
}
```

what am i doing wrong please.

Comment: Try to add wildcard to your dataGroups's API URL instead of using constant url.
Change `https://naipod.com/naipodapi/getsongs` to `"https://naipod.com/naipodapi/*` in **ngsw-config.json**. Remember that you need to enter first to that page (have cached api value) to get data offline

Comment: Perhaps try playing with the "start_url": "/" - Not sure if that may help, but your app is currently not at the root of your site.

Comment: Hello Mathias, how do i get sure that my app is currently  at the root of your site. Thanks

Comment: Your app is currently home here:  https://naipod.com/home/music. Is that temporary and the eventual plan is https://naipod.com?  Try playing with "start_url": "/home/music/"  Not sure if it will work for you.